# Using different vehicles in sequence while commuting

Tags: word-request

How to describe a commute when you use different kinds of vehicles without walking?

Imagine you use 3 different vehicles to get to work.First bus, then metro and then a shuttle but bus leaves you at the metro station and the shuttle takes you just outside of the metro station you leave. Therefore, you do not need to walk to get on  to one vehicles  to another.

- A: How to commute to work?
- B: I take three different vehicles.
- A: It must be tiring do you walk a lot?
- B: Only walk to the bust stop and then I ...............(between vehicles).

Can I use *hop on/off* or they are just another  words for getting on/off for this context?

Comment: Yes, **hop  onto the metro** would indicate that the shuttle drops you off right at the metro station and there is only a very short walk from the shuttle  stop to the metro.

Comment: Aside from the grammar question, I'd call it "my typical morning commute" (car train bike).  :)

Answer (score 4):

> hop on

has the same meaning as *get on* but implies the travel is easy and enjoyable.

> It's simple, to get to Paris, all you need to do is **hop on** a plane.
>   I'll just **hop in** a cab and come right over!

To describe your commute, you could say

> I'm three **hops** away.  *(sounds easy)*
>   I have to **take** a bus **then** the metro **then** a shuttle to get to work. *(doesn't sound so easy)*
>   I'm three **transfers** away,
>   I have to transfer three times to get to work.

Answer (score 3):

- ... I transfer between three vehicles.
- ... I switch between three vehicles.
- ... I end up taking three vehicles.
- ... I end up riding a bus, the metro, and a shuttle.
- ... I ride three vehicles.
- ... I end hopping onto three vehicles total.
- ... I end up using three vehicles.

*Ride*, *take*, and *use* are pretty much interchangeable.  *Transfer* would be a best fit if you buy one ticket or pass that supports all three modes.